# Length function in Matlab to python

Tags: python, matlab

I am attempting to translate the following Matlab code into python

`d=real(ifft(fft(fw).*conj(fft(rv))))`

`d=[d(ld+1:length(d)) d(1:ld)]'`

but the problem occurs in the following line of code:

`ld=length(d)`

My question is about the length function in matlab. How do I translate this correctly to python, to get an integer? I have tried `np.size(d,1)` and `np.prod(d.shape)`. But both of these return a 'list' and not a integer. Is there an easier way on how to do this?

Comment: `len(d)` is the appropriate method. If you work with numpy arrays, then use `d.shape`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `length` in Matlab return the maximum length of the matrix among its dimensions, if `d` is a numpy array in python you can write:

```py
ld = max(d.shape)
```

For example, if `d` has `(10, 30, 20)` dimension, the value of `ld` will be `30`.